# Как подключить swf в action script?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Как подключить swf в action script ?

пробовал вот так

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.[yourdomain].com/externalSwf.swf"); 
var loader:Loader = new Loader() 
loader.load(request); 
addChild(loader);
```

не получается, не отображается подключаемая флэшка.

вот полный код:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author
     */
    [SWF(width = "400", height = "400")]
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        public function Main()
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://test.devel/externalSwf.swf"); 
            var loader:Loader = new Loader() 
            loader.load(request); 
            addChild(loader);


            loader.scaleX  = 400;
            loader.scaleY = 400;
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть небольшое, но все же количество. По этому нужно действовать методом исключения. Для начала Вам нужно подписать экземпляр Loader под события всех доступных ошибок и статусов -

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _loader:Loader;

        public function Main() 
        {
            this._loader = new Loader();
            super.addChild(this._loader);

            this._loader.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderInfo_completeHandler);
            this._loader.loaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderInfo_ioErrorHandler);
            this._loader.loaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, loaderInfo_httpStatusHandler);

            try 
            {
                this._loader.load(new URLRequest(''));
            }
            catch (error:Error)
            {
                trace(error.message);
            }

        }

        private function loaderInfo_httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void 
        {
            trace(event.type, event.status);
        }

        private function loaderInfo_ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void 
        {
            trace(event.type, event.text);
        }

        private function loaderInfo_completeHandler(event:Event):void 
        {
            trace(event.type);
        }

    }

}
```

Код выше поможет выявить проблему. И скорее всего эта проблема будет связана с crossdomain.xml, который должен находится на сервере и говорить ему, что у Вас есть разрешение на скачку контента.

Comment: Сетевые запросы флэшки должны быть видны в Хроме, в веб-инспекторе, поэтому можно заглянуть туда. Кросс-доменные проблемы будут видны.